# How to calculate the minimum amount based on user input value

Tags: r, min

Here i get the csv file containing 4706 observations,then i need to build a 'best hostptal'function that based on the state and keyword user input to calculate the min heart attack, heart failure,pneumonia rate in different hospitals in different state, then return the first hosiptal name in the ascending order.

Below is the part code i wrote, but i was stuck in how to calculate the minimum value based on the state  user input. For example, if user inputs NY, then find the min heart attack rate, then return the hospital name in NY

```
best<-function(state,outcome){
a<-read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv",na.string="Not Available")
if(!state %in% a[,7])
print ("invalid state")
if(outcome=="heart attack")
bd<-suppressWarnings(as.numeric(as.character(a[,11])))
.... 
}
```

The data sample may be like:

```
Hospital   State    deaths in heart attack   deaths in heart failure 

L hospital  NY       10.1                     10.2

S hospital  NY       10.2                     10.5

M hospital  AZ       18.0                     14.5

Z hospital  AZ       14.0                     14.5
```

The expected result is :

```
best("NY", "heart attack")

[1] L Hospital

best("AZ", "heart failure")

[1] "M Hostpital"
```

Please note that heart attack rate in the file is a `factor` variable, so i need to convert it to `numeric`, how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: I have added sample file and expected result, sorry for that, i will pay more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps

```
best <- function(dat, St, keyword){
  nm1 <- grep(keyword, names(dat))
  i1 <- dat[["State"]] == St
  Subdat <- dat[i1,]
  Subdat[["Hospital"]][which.min(Subdat[,nm1])]
 }

best(df1, "NY", "heart attack")
#[1] "L hospital"
best(df1, "AZ", "heart failure")
#[1] "M hospital"
```

NOTE: It is not clear which column is `heart attack rate`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Hospital = c("L hospital", "S hospital", 
"M hospital", 
"Z hospital"), State = c("NY", "NY", "AZ", "AZ"), 
`deaths in heart attack` = c(10.1, 
10.2, 18, 14), `deaths in heart failure` = c(10.2, 10.5, 14.5, 
14.5)), .Names = c("Hospital", "State", "deaths in heart attack", 
"deaths in heart failure"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```